# Boost document in Solr

Tags: solr, solr-boost

i'd like to boost documents in solr only if a certain field has a fixed value
for example:

i'd like to boost all documents that have the value of the field colour set to "yellow"

`bf=colour:yellow^10`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With edismax, you can do this:

```
bf=if(exists(query({!v='colour:yellow'})),10,1)
```

which is a function query.

Ref:

- See point 3 here for function query:
  https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Using_FunctionQuery
- For the value query syntax, see
  https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#exists